# Google Apps and Retrieving Google Plus UserID

Tags: google-plus

We currently have Google Apps for Education in use and have enabled Google Plus.  I have looked at many of the API's google offers https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and have had no luck in finding an answer.

I'd like to be able to query the user in google apps and find out their Google Plus ID.

Google+ has its own API and I know is in beta for education so it may simply be that they haven't added to this list: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/ under application API's.

Is it possible with a combination of calls maybe to get the Google Plus user ID from our users email?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do, as far as I know, you can't just lookup someone's Google+ id in your system given their email.

However, if the user signs in, you can get the user id as described on the History client side starter [Google+ history client-side flow](https://developers.google.com/+/history/client-side-flow). Instead of writing moments, you read the profile and then can retrieve the id for their Google+ account. You will need a client id from the [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) with the Google+ service enabled, same as the client-side flow. Once you have this id, you can create the HTML page that will get the Google+ id using the JavaScript client.

The following code shows how you can do this:

```
<html>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSignInCallback(authResult){
    // Set the access token on the JavaScript API Client
    gapi.auth.setToken(authResult);

    var args = {
      'path': '/plus/v1moments/people/me',
      'method': 'GET',
      'callback': function(response) {
        var profile = response;
        console.log(profile);
        alert('id is ' + profile.id);
      }
    };
    gapi.client.request(args);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <!-- Render the sign-in button -->
  <g:plus action="connect"
          clientid="YOUR CLIENT ID"
          scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
          callback="onSignInCallback"></g:plus>
</body>
</html>
```

When you run the above code, it will popup the signed in user's ID as an alert. If you're trying to do this for a non-Google (e.g. GMail) account, log in with your domain credentials to get that Google+ account id.

Here is a [demo of this code](http://wheresgus.com/profiledemo/).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the answer posted on Dec 4 2012 to work, perhaps the google+ api changed since then, or I just missed something. However, I did get the profile info (including id that the original poster wanted) using google's quickstart example:

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these simple steps to find your Google Plus User ID:

1) Login to your Google+ account.

2) From the side menu click on the Profile icon

3) In the address bar you will see your complete Google+ URL. It will look something like this:

https://plus.google.com/100009709084787102522/posts

4) Your Google Plus User ID is the long series of numbers. in this instance my Google+ ID is the following:

100009709084787102522
```

Reference : http://www.jumpmobi.com/miscellaneous/what-is-my-google-google-plus-user-id/